# Replacing items in a list in a dictionary with items from another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dictionaries:

```
d1 = {"00f_5" :[1,2,3], "00f_6": [1,2,3]}

d2 = [{"marker":"00f_5",1: 'AAA'},{"marker":"00f_6", 1: 'CCC'},{"marker":"00f_5", 2:"AAC"}]
```

I would like the following output:

```
d1 = {"00f_5" :["AAA","AAC",3], "00f_6": ["CCC",2,3]}
```

I have tried multiple attempts, but I couldn't get it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post what you have attempted so far, and where did you encounter problems. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a dict that maps the marker to a sub-dict that maps numeric keys to the 3-letter codes, so that given a marker and a numeric key, you can use `dict.get` method to get the mapped code if it exists:

```
d = {}
for s in d2:
    d.setdefault(s['marker'], {}).update(s)
d1 = {k: [d[k].get(i, i) for i in l] for k, l in d1.items()}
```

so that given:

```
d1 = {"00f_5" :[1,2,3], "00f_6": [1,2,3]}
d2 = [{"marker":"00f_5",1: 'AAA'},{"marker":"00f_6", 1: 'CCC'},{"marker":"00f_5", 2:"AAC"}]
```

`d1` will become:

```
{'00f_5': ['AAA', 'AAC', 3], '00f_6': ['CCC', 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I will not give you the full program, you might try to understand and play with the following code:

```py
d2 = [{"marker":"00f_5",1: 'AAA'},{"marker":"00f_6", 1: 'CCC'},{"marker":"00f_5", 2:"AAC"}]

for d in d2:
  for key, value in d.items():
    if key == "marker":
      marker = value
    else:
      reference = value
      content = key
  print("Marker: {}, Reference: {}, Content: {}".format(marker, reference, content))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest overwriting the first dict.  Just make a new one (`d3`).

**Given**

```
d1 = {"00f_5" :[1,2,3], "00f_6": [1,2,3]}

lst = [
    {"marker":"00f_5",1: 'AAA'}, 
    {"marker":"00f_6", 1: 'CCC'},
    {"marker":"00f_5", 2:"AAC"}
]
```

**Code**

```
d3 = {}
for d in lst:
    key = d["marker"]
    value = d1[key]
    for k, v in d.items():     
    if not isinstance(k, int):                         # skip to numeric keys
            continue
        if key not in d3:                              # fill missing entries
            d3[key] = value
        idx = k - 1
        d3[key][idx] = v                               # overwrite list item

d3
{'00f_5': ['AAA', 'AAC', 3], '00f_6': ['CCC', 2, 3]}
```